# 'str' object does not support item assignment - with Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have created a custom template tag in django

```
disqusTag.py:

register = template.Library()
@register.inclusion_tag('polls/questionDetail.html', takes_context=True)
def disqus_sso(context):
    DISQUS_SECRET_KEY = getattr(settings, 'DISQUS_SECRET_KEY', None)
    if DISQUS_SECRET_KEY is None:
        return "<p>You need to set DISQUS_SECRET_KEY before you can use SSO</p>"

    DISQUS_PUBLIC_KEY = getattr(settings, 'DISQUS_PUBLIC_KEY', None)
    if DISQUS_PUBLIC_KEY is None:
        return "<p>You need to set DISQUS_PUBLIC_KEY before you can use SSO</p>"

    user = context['user']

    if user.is_anonymous():
        return ""

    data = json.dumps({
        'id': user.id,
        'username': user.username,
        'email': user.email,
    })

    # encode the data to base64
    message = base64.b64encode(data.encode('utf-8'))

    # generate a timestamp for signing the message
    timestamp = int(time.time())

    key = DISQUS_SECRET_KEY.encode('utf-8')
    msg = ('%s %s' % (message, timestamp)).encode('utf-8')
    digestmod = hashlib.sha1

    # generate our hmac signature
    sig = hmac.HMAC(key, msg, digestmod).hexdigest()

    return  dict(
        message=message,
        timestamp=timestamp,
        sig=sig,
        pub_key=DISQUS_PUBLIC_KEY,
    )

    t = get_template('polls/questionDetail.html')
    register.inclusion_tag(t)(disqus_sso)
```

and i am loading the same in my template questionDetail.html as

```
{% load disqusTag %}
{% disqus_sso %}
```

but i am getting this error : 'str' object does not support item assignment

can anybody help me why? I know similar questions have been asked on stack overflow, but i went through all of them and none of them helped.

Comment: At which line of code does this error appears ?

Answer (score 2):

You should have provided the full traceback.

However, I think the issue is with your `if user.is_anonymous` check - if it's true, you return an empty string. But the return value of an inclusion tag must always be a context dict. You should return an empty dict there instead.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. This was the issue in my case.